# Can't connect to firebase in Android - Gradle config error

Tags: java, android, firebase, build.gradle, google-signin

The error is: Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync.

My code:

```
 dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'



implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
```

What Im doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: check if this  line is present in build.gradle file,  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: I got it, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message does not match the title the least ...

Remove the `:19.0.0` when using Firebase BOM.

There may be further errors in the rest of the `build.gradle`.